# (Python + selenium) how to click on "onclick" element?

Tags: python, selenium, onclick, click

```
<a href="#none" onclick="MemberAction.snsLogin('googleplus', '%2Findex.html')">

<img src="http://img.echosting.cafe24.com/skin/base_ko_KR/member/btn_google_login.gif" alt="구글 로그인"></a>
```

I wanted to click on that element, so I tried a few things.

however it said an NoSuchElementExeption error

What else can I try?

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="member_form_8077679061"]/div/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a').click()
```

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#member_form_3934077016 > div > div.ifwc-easy > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a').click()
```

Comment: Where did you get the xpath string you're using in the first example?

Comment: so it might be that the id that you are trying to select changes each time the page loads (you gave two similar xpaths with different Id's for the path) in which case the value that you are looking won't be constant and won't be found by selenium -- instead use a non-changing value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element you are trying to click on could not be there when the webdriver searches for it on the page, which is one potential explanation. This may occur if the element is added dynamically to the page after it has loaded or if the page is still loading when the webdriver attempts to locate the element. In this situation, you may consider pausing the script's execution with an explicit wait until the element appears on the page before attempting to click on it.

You can try something like this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

locator = (By.XPATH, 'my-element')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator))
```